# PHP object like array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to be able to set my object like this:

```
$obj->foo = 'bar';
```

then I need to use it as an array like that:

```
if($obj['foo'] == 'bar'){
  //more code here
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try extending [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)

You'll also need to implement a `__get` [Magic Method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) as Valentin Golev mentioned.

Your class will need to looks something like this:

```
Class myClass extends ArrayObject {
    // class property definitions...
    public function __construct()
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }

    public function __get($n) { return $this[$n]; }

    // Other methods
}
```

Comment: I have this 

class Obj extends ArrayObject{} 

But when i am doing my unit testing i get a failure on the above.

Comment: yes, now you need to define there function __get() and __set(). For example, function __get($n) { return $this[$n]; }

Comment: Thank you very much, i was missing the helper function.

Answer (score 23):

Just add `implements ArrayAccess` to your class and add the required methods:

- public function offsetExists($offset)
- public function offsetGet($offset)
- public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
- public function offsetUnset($offset)

See http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Answer (score 17):

[ArrayObject](http://docs.php.net/class.arrayobject) implements the ArrayAccess interface (and some more). Using the [ARRAY_AS_PROPS](http://docs.php.net/class.arrayobject#arrayobject.constants.array-as-props) flag it provides the functionality you're looking for.

```
$obj = new ArrayObject(array(), ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
$obj->foo = 'bar';
echo $obj['foo'];
```

Alternatively you can implement the [ArrayAccess](http://docs.php.net/class.arrayaccess.php) interface in one of your own classes:

```
class Foo implements ArrayAccess {
  public function offsetExists($offset) {
    return isset($this->$offset);
  }

  public function offsetGet($offset) {
    return $this->$offset;
  }

  public function offsetSet($offset , $value) {
    $this->$offset = $value;
  }

  public function offsetUnset($offset) {
    unset($this->$offset);
  }
}

$obj = new Foo;
$obj->foo = 'bar';
echo $obj['foo'];
```

Answer (score 10):

You can access PHP object as PHP array, but in different ways. Try this:

```
$obj->{'foo'}
```

That is similar with accessing array like this:

```
$arr['foo']
```

You can also do this:

```
$propertyName = 'foo';
$obj->$propertyName; // same like first example
```

Comment: Upvoting because syntactical sugar.

Comment: Doesn't convert the object to an actual array.

Answer (score 9):

You'll have to implement the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface to be able to do that -- which only means implementing a few *(4 to be exact)* simple methods :

- [`ArrayAccess::offsetExists`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetexists.php) : Whether or not an offset exists.
- [`ArrayAccess::offsetGet`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetget.php) : Returns the value at specified offset.
- [`ArrayAccess::offsetSet`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetset.php) : Assigns a value to the specified offset.
- and [`ArrayAccess::offsetUnset`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetunset.php) : Unsets an offset.

There is a full example on the manual's page I pointed to ;-)

Comment: @Gordon : ergh, thanks ! I generally copy-paste the names of classes/methods to avoid that kind of mistake... This time I thought "I can type this"... Well, it seems not ^^

Answer (score 9):

You're mixing objects and arrays. You can create and access an object like so:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->foo = 'bar';

if($obj->foo == 'bar'){
// true
}
```

and an array like so:

```
$obj = new Array();
$obj['foo'] = 'bar';

if($obj['foo'] == 'bar'){
// true
}
```

You can define a class and add implements ArrayAccess if you want to access your class as both an array and a class.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 3):

Your object must implement the [`ArrayAccess`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface, then PHP will allow you to use the square brackets like that.

Answer (score 3):

You could also cast the object as an array:

```
if((array)$obj['foo'] == 'bar'){
  //more code here
}
```

Comment: The expression `(array)$obj['foo']` as given here applies the array conversion to the object used as an array, which gives a fatal error. What you want is ((array)$obj)['foo']. Then it appears to work much simpler than any of the other answers. You can convert an object to a true array like this: `$arr=(array)$obj;`. So simple.

Answer (score 2):

## Enhance Class capability with no functionality drawbacks

You can also use ArrayAccess to access a single array property in your class and leave other properties being accessed in OOP way. Yet still it will work as you requested.

```
class Foo implements \ArrayAccess
{

/**
* mixed[] now you can access this array using your object 
* like a normal array Foo['something'] = 'blablabla'; echo  Foo['something']; ... and so on
* other properties will remain accessed as normal: $Foo->getName();
*/
private myArrayOptions = [];

private $name = 'lala';

    ...

    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->myArrayOptions[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        if ($this->offsetExists($offset)) {
            return $this->myArrayOptions[$offset];
        }

        return null; // or throw the exception;
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        $this->myArrayOptions[$offset] = $value;
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        unset($this->myArrayOptions[$offset]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function __set($offset, $value){
        $this->myArrayOptions[$offset] = $value;
    }

    ...

}
```

The above will work as you expected.

```
$obj->foo = 'bar';
if($obj['foo'] == 'bar'){
    echo "WoWo";
}
```

Also note that Foo['name'] **!==** Foo->getName() 
those a two different variables