# Object acting like an array? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, orm, object

I have seen something like this in an ORM:

```
    $b = new Book();
    $b->limit(5)->get();

    echo 'ID: ' . $b->id . '<br />';
    echo 'Name: ' . $b->title . '<br />';
    echo 'Description: ' . $b->description . '<br />';
    echo 'Year: ' . $b->year . '<br />';

    foreach ($b as $book)
    {
        echo 'ID: ' . $book->id . '<br />';
        echo 'Name: ' . $book->title . '<br />';
        echo 'Description: ' . $book->description . '<br />';
        echo 'Year: ' . $book->year . '<br />';
        echo '<br />';
    }
```

How is it possible that an object acts as both array and object? How can I accomplish that?
I was hoping to see a new __magic method or something in Book's parent class, but I couldn't find anything, so there might be something really basic about php objects that I don't know.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12):

Objects that implement the [`Traversable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface (through [`Iterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) or [`IteratorAggregate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php)) support the `foreach` construct, if that's what you mean by "acting as an array." Eg:

```
class theClass implements Iterator {
    // implement iterator here
}

// now you can do
$obj = new theClass;

foreach ($obj as $value) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Actually every object can be taversed with foreach, but it will access all public properties. You need to implement `Iterator` if you want to change this behaviour. Another interface you might be interested in is `ArrayAccess`

Answer (score 6):

You do not have to do anything special to use `foreach` with objects.

From the [PHP manual on Object Iteration](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php):

> PHP 5 provides a way for objects to be defined so it is possible to iterate through a list of items, with, for example a foreach statement. By default, all visible properties will be used for the iteration.

Example:

```
class Foo
{
    public $foo = 1;
    protected $bar = 2;
    private $baz = 3;
}

foreach(new Foo as $prop) echo $prop; // outputs 1 only
```

Your class does not have to implement `Traversable` as suggested elsewhere and in fact, the class above doesn't:

```
var_dump (new Foo instanceof Traversable); // FALSE
```

You *can* implement one of the [Iterator](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) or [IteratorAggregate](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php) if you need more control over how the iteration should behave:

```
class Foo implements IteratorAggregate
{
    public $foo = 1;
    protected $bar = 2;
    private $baz = 3;

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return new ArrayIterator((array) $this);
    }
}

foreach(new Foo as $prop) echo $prop; // outputs 123
```

Because `Iterator` and `IteratorAggregate` extend `Traversable`, your class will now also be an instance of `Traversable`, but like shown above, it's not necessary for iterating the object.

```
var_dump (new Foo instanceof Traversable); // TRUE
```

You can also use an [ArrayObject](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) to make the object behave like a hybrid between class and object. Or you can implement [ArrayAccess](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) to allow accessing the class with square brackets. You can also subclass the class to be [one of the Iterators](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) PHP provides.

Further reading:

- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL.html
- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL-ArrayAccess.html
- [PHP object like array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007695/php-object-like-array)