# Is it possible to implement an array-like object in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, magic-methods

I want to implement an object that behaves like an array. It should be used in this way:

```
$var = new CustomCollection(retrieveFromWebService());
echo $var[0]; // legal
$var[0] = 'a'; // illegal
```

Can this be done in PHP, using magic methods or another mechanism?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP object like array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007695/php-object-like-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `CustomCollection` class will need to implement the built-in [`ArrayAccess` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).

See also: http://code.google.com/p/phpraise/source/browse/trunk/phpraise/core/collection/RaiseCollection.php

Comment: Is it possible to "partially implement" an interface?

Comment: nope. An interface requires the class to implement all of its methods unless the implementation is an interface or abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

I think [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) is what you are looking for.